# Sending Notification when CPU Usage is 90% or above

Tags: bash, shell-script

I am trying to send Discord notification when CPU usage is 90% or above. I tried several things but getting error at line 15. How should I compare these 2 variables `"$CPU_USAGE" -ge "$MAX_CPU_USAGE"`. Everything else is working fine.

This is the error which I am getting.

```
$ sudo bash -x /home/mp/cpu_usage.sh 

[sudo] password for mp: 
 + WEBHOOK_URL=<web-hook-url> 
 + MAX_CPU_USAGE=90 
 + true 
 + ++ top -bn2 
 + ++ grep %Cpu 
++ tail -1 
++ grep -P '(....|...) id,' 
++ awk '{print 100-$8}' 
 + CPU_USAGE=60.2 
 + '[' 60.2 -ge 90 ']' 
 + /home/mp/cpu_usage.sh: line 15: [: 60.2: integer expression expected
   + sleep 30
```

Script -

```
#!/bin/bash

# Set the Discord webhook URL
WEBHOOK_URL="<web-hook-url>"

# Set the maximum CPU usage threshold (in percent)
MAX_CPU_USAGE=90

while true; do
  # Get the current CPU usage
  #CPU_USAGE=$(grep 'cpu' /proc/stat | awk '{usage=($2+$4)*100/($2+$4+$5)} END {print usage "%"}')
  CPU_USAGE=$(top -bn2 | grep '%Cpu' | tail -1 | grep -P '(....|...) id,'|awk '{print 100-$8}')

  # Check if the CPU usage is above the threshold
  if [ "$CPU_USAGE" -ge "$MAX_CPU_USAGE" ] ; then
    # Construct the message to send to Discord
    MESSAGE="CPU usage is HIGH"

    # Send the message to Discord using the webhook
    curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d "{\"content\":\"$MESSAGE\"}" $WEBHOOK_URL
  fi

  # Sleep for half a minute before checking again
  sleep 30
done
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and also copy&paste the error you are getting at line 15. Run your script with `bash -x yourscript` to see what command actually gets executed. The value of `CPU_USAGE` might not be what you expect. If it is a floating point number, then you cannot compare it in a `bash` script, but you could do the comparison in `awk`. BTW: The `grep` and `tail` commands can probably be implemented as part of the the `awk` script.

Comment: I am getting error - integer expresison expected. Now I understand why I am getting the error, but how do I rectify it?

Comment: **Please [edit] your question to provide requested information**, don't use comments for this purpose. Please copy&paste the output of `top -bn2` on your system. This will help to test a proposed solution. (The output might look different on my system.)

Comment: I have a script for that: https://github.com/birdie-github/useful-scripts/blob/master/alert-bad-processes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message

```
 + /home/mp/cpu_usage.sh: line 15: [: 60.2: integer expression expected
```

from the command

```
 + '[' 60.2 -ge 90 ']'
```

makes clear that your code tries to compare a floating point value while the `[` command of the shell expects integer values. In contrast to the shell, `awk` can do floating point calculations.

One way to fix the problem is to convert the floating point value to an integer value as suggested in [Stephen Harris](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/168757/stephen-harris)' [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/728186/330217).

The script can be improved in a way that needs less processes. You can integrate the comparison and the `grep` and `tail` commands into the `awk` script.

I think the command `grep -P '(....|...) id,'` is useless because there is always a sequence of 3 or 4 characters and a space before `id,`.

```
MAX_CPU_USAGE=90

while true; do
  # Get the current CPU usage
  
  # Check if the CPU usage is above the threshold
  if top -bn2 | awk -v "max_cpu=$MAX_CPU_USAGE" '/^%Cpu/ { idle=$8 } END { if((100-idle)>max_cpu) exit 1 }'
  then
    # Construct the message to send to Discord
    MESSAGE="CPU usage is HIGH"

    # Send the message to Discord using the webhook
    curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d "{\"content\":\"$MESSAGE\"}" $WEBHOOK_URL
  fi

  # Sleep for half a minute before checking again
  sleep 30
done
```

Explanation of the `awk` command:

- `-v "max_cpu=$MAX_CPU_USAGE"` = Pass the shell variable to `awk` as a variable.
- `/^%Cpu/ { idle=$8 }` = Store the the 8th field as the idle value from any matching `%Cpu` line, the variable will end up with the last one.
- `END { if((100-idle)>max_cpu) exit 1 }` = Limit check at the end of the input. `awk` will exit with code 1 if the value is over the limit, otherwise exit 0.
- The `if` checks the exit code of `awk` as the last command of the pipe.

Answer (score 2):

The problem you are likely hitting is that the value of `CPU_USAGE` is not an integer; e.g. on my machine just now I got `0.3` as the value.

The `-ge` test can only compare integers.

An easy way of solving this is to modify your `awk` to `print int(100-$8)` so the number is always an integer.